# Render Vector Tiles Layer with WMS/WMTS QGIS Server

Tags: qgis, wms, vector-tiles, qgis-server, wmts

I have a project with Vector Tiles layer ([https://panoramax.openstreetmap.fr/api/map/{z}/{x}/{y}.mvt](https://panoramax.openstreetmap.fr/api/map/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.mvt)). The project has other test layers. It is perfectly rendered in QGIS Desktop (3.34.2) both test layers and Vector Tiles layer. The project is served by a QGIS Server (3.22.4) with WMS and WMTS. Test layers are rendered and served but the Vector Tiles layer is not rendered yet served. Do you know why ? Or do you know a workaround to render and serve Vector Tiles layer with QGIS Server ?

Comment: QGIS server doesn't seem to support vector tiles as an output format ~ looking at GetMap formats in https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/server_manual/services/wms.html#getmap

Comment: Thank you @nmtoken. I am not looking to serve vector tiles but to render them and serve the render in WMTS. And the rendering works on QGIS Desktop but not on QGIS Server even if the layer is served.

Comment: I confused, in your question you have `and serve Vector Tiles` but in your comment you say you are not looking to serve them.    Do you mean you want to use vector tiles as as data source?

Comment: Yes I am looking to serve in WMTS the rendering of the vector tiles layer. It is actually served but the result is empty tiles (fully transparent raster tiles).